# Plotting a survey data to a bar chart

Tags: matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

i have a dataframe which has columns as 'City, 'Gender','Education level' and 'How satisfied are you about something'

So i am trying to plot it into a bar chart;

```
#in here i select the neighbourhood as "X"
#then i group it based on gender and try to plot it with the question of how satisfied are you about something.
```

So this is what i got:

But i'd like to get something like this:

I could not figure out to make the bars same color as the answers of the question of 'How satisfied are you about something'.

And i want to be able to add percentages at the top of the bar charts. If someone can guide me I would be really greatful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Seaborn [`countplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) as follows. Using `gender` for the `x` places it on the x-axis.  Using `Satisfied?` as the `hue` will divide the bars for the genders into smaller bars and create an accompanying legend. If you want to fix a certain order on these values, either `hue_order` could be used, or the column could be made categorical.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

N = 500
data = pd.DataFrame({'City': np.random.choice(['Test City', 'Other City'], N),
                     'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], N),
                     'Satisfied?': np.random.choice(['1 - very bad', '2 - bad', '3 - neutral', '4 - good', '5 - very good'], N)})
sns.countplot(data=data[data['City'] == 'Test City'], x='Gender', palette='plasma',
              hue='Satisfied?', hue_order=['1 - very bad', '2 - bad', '3 - neutral', '4 - good', '5 - very good'])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

From here, further refinements can be made:

- Changing the bar heights such that the sum per gender will be one. This will convert the heights to percents.
- Change the formatting of the y-axis to show percents
- While changing the heights, also the widths of the bars could be changed, leaving a little gap between them
- Putting the legend at the bottom, without frame and with square markers.
- Add the percentage as text above the bars
- Add horizontal grid lines
- Hide the spines
- ...

Seaborn has a [myriad of ways to choose colors](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html). The simplest way is to give a list of [named colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names). But not that existing palettes have been studied to have colors that go well together.  The [Colorbrewer website](https://colorbrewer2.org) can be used to experiment and find colors for many situations.

The variable `width_scale` in the code can be used to set the gaps. In the old version `0.8` was set, leaving a gap of `0.2`. The new example has a gap of `1.0 - 0.6 = 0.4`.

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

N = 500
data = pd.DataFrame({'City': np.random.choice(['Test City', 'Other City'], N),
                     'Gender': np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], N, p=[0.3, 0.7]),
                     'Satisfied?': np.random.choice(['1 - very bad', '2 - bad', '3 - neutral', '4 - good', '5 - very good'], N)})
city_data = data[data['City'] == 'Test City']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 4))
sns.countplot(data=city_data, x='Gender', order=['Male', 'Female'], ax=ax,
              palette=['turquoise', 'tomato', 'deepskyblue', 'gold', 'limegreen'],
              hue='Satisfied?', hue_order=['1 - very bad', '2 - bad', '3 - neutral', '4 - good', '5 - very good'])

width_scale = 0.6  # the relative width of the bars, 1.0 means bars touching; the gap will be 1-width_scale
for bars in ax.containers:
    for bar, total_per_gender in zip(bars, [sum(city_data['Gender'] == 'Male'), sum(city_data['Gender'] == 'Female')]):
        new_height = bar.get_height() / total_per_gender
        bar.set_height(new_height)
        width = bar.get_width()
        x = bar.get_x()
        bar.set_width(width * width_scale)
        bar.set_x(x + width * (1 - width_scale) / 2)  # recenter
        if np.isnan(new_height):
            new_height = 0
        ax.text(x + width / 2, new_height, f' {new_height * 100:.1f}%\n', ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
ax.set_xlabel('')  # remove superfluous x-label
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0, labelsize=14)  # remove tick marks, larger text
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
ax.grid(axis='y', ls=':', clip_on=False)
sns.despine(fig, ax, top=True, right=True, left=True, bottom=True)
ax.legend(ncol=5, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), loc='upper center', frameon=False, handlelength=1, handleheight=1)
ax.autoscale()  # needed to recalculate the axis limits after changing the heights
ax.relim()
ax.margins(y=0.15, x=0.02)  # some space for the text on top of the bars
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example percentage plot]

Comment: Ok. I was able to get it done, but correct me if i am wrong, if i do not any count of one 
specific label for this time let's say "Master Students", then it is not gonna put it in the charts?

Comment: And one last thing i would like to ask, how can i change the percentage text 90 degree to the left?  Instead of this "-" , i want it to be like " | "

Comment: I was wondering one more thing, if there is no data exists for specific answer but there are other answers is there a way to show it as "%0"? For example this case

[link](https://imgur.com/lKAW5Cu)

Comment: It seems that currently the bars get a height of "Not a number (`nan`)" instead of zero. I updated the code to test for `np.isnan()`. Maybe that works for you?

Comment: It works! I was wondering if you could point me towards a good source (book or a video) to learn more about plotting?

Comment: Depending on the type of plots you want to create, Jake vander Plas' [Python Data Science Handbook](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/index.html) seems interesting. Full contents and code examples are available on github. Apart from that, just plotting the data you find interesting, trying to improve, looking for answers on StackOverflow and in the official documentation.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to specifically set colors to bars (i found different palets but i'd like set them to a specific colors) and change the gap (increase it) between bars?

Comment: I was able to increase the gap between the bars and i also changed the fontsize for the percentage representation however, it looked like this 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/ihGySLI) 

I changed the bar size and text fontsize however i was not able to solve this messy look. 
 
width_scale = 0.5
`
ax.text(x + width / 2, new_height, f'{new_height * 100:.1f} %\n', ha='center', va='center', fontsize = 8)`

Do you think there is a way to overcome this? @JohanC

Comment: I also tried to increase the subplot figuresize, but i am wondering if there is another possible solution.

Comment: The messy look comes from the labels overlapping. Setting a smaller fontsize helps. Making the text shorter (e.g. leaving out the space and/or the last digit as in `f'{new_height * 100:.0f}%\n')` also helps. You could make the number of digits conditional, for example `f'{new_height * 100:.1f}%\n' if new_height > 0.001 else '0%\n'`

Comment: What if i wanted to plot the entire dataset filtered in a specific column for example from the dataframe you created "Satisfied" but not based on "Gender" or anything, just the entire satisfaction with the same idea, percentages etc. I have tried to plot several times i could not make it work just like your example.